# Given binary tree create linkedlist of all the nodes at each depth (BFS or DFS)

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to figure out the solution for the above given problem. I came up with a solution, but I am not sure if that will work successfully.

```
public Node LinkedListOfNodes(Node root, Map<Integer, LinkedList<Node>> mapOfLinkedList, int level)
    {

        if(root == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final LinkedList<Node> linkedListOfNodes = new LinkedList();
        level = level+1;

        linkedListOfNodes.add(LinkedListOfNodes(root.left, mapOfLinkedList, level));
        linkedListOfNodes.add(LinkedListOfNodes(root.right,mapOfLinkedList,level));

        mapOfLinkedList.put(level,linkedListOfNodes);

        return root;
    }
```

Is this solution right? Can a better approach be taken? Can a BFS approach be the right approach here or DFS will work better?

This is how I had implemented BFS. I can modify it to work for this problem.

```
public void BFS(Graph graph, Vertex source) {

        final Queue<Vertex> queue = new PriorityQueue();

        for(Vertex vertex : graph.vertices) {
            vertex.color = "WHITE";
            vertex.distance = 0;
            vertex.parent = null;
        }

        source.distance = 0;
        source.parent = null;
        source.color = "GRAY";

        queue.add(source);

        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            Vertex u = queue.element();
            for (Vertex vertex : graph.adj.get(u))
            {
                if (vertex.color == "WHITE")
                {
                    vertex.color = "GRAY";
                    vertex.distance = vertex.distance + u.distance;
                    vertex.parent = u;

                    queue.add(vertex);
                }
            }

            u.color = "BLACK";
        }

    }


    class Graph {

        List<Vertex> vertices;
        Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adj;
    }

    class Vertex {
        int distance;
        Vertex parent;
        String color;
    }
```

Comment: Is this solution right?  - is it working as expected and did you run it?

Comment: So you want separate linkedlists for the nodes at a different depth? i.e. 1 linkedlist for nodes at depth 1, 1 linkedlist for nodes at depth 2..

Comment: Yes, thats what the question meant, I guess. If you tree with depth D, you will have D linkedList.

Comment: If that's the case, BFS will seem to make more sense?

Comment: I traced it through mnually, but to make it actually work with inputs, I am working on creating binary tree (Nodes with data) and passing it to this solution.

Comment: Do that. Add unit tests. Come back if you have a concrete issue.

Comment: `mapOfLinkedList.put(level,linkedListOfNodes);` has the new level (1 too much). And the level list should only be created when it is not in the map.

Comment: hmm. Thanks a lot guys for looking into it. I will add timer around my solution to determine how much time it takes for BFS, DFS and the above solution (modification to post-order), and post the result here.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: why do we need a check for creating a link list at every level in my solution? At every level I am creating a list, adding nodes to it and at that level adding it to the map by the level value.

Comment: you dont need the for loop inside the while in bfs of tree traversal.You need to check left and right links and add them in linklist

Comment: Both the left node and the right node will create a list of nodes for the same level+1.

Comment: Yea. I was about to mention that. I realized it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code which will solve your problem:

```
Map<Integer, List<Node>> mapOfLinkedList = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node>>();

void addNode(Node root, int level) {
    List levelList = mapOfLinkedList.get(level);  // get List for current level
    if (levelList == null) {
        levelList = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }
    levelList.add(root);                          // add Node to the current level

    if (root.left != null) {                      // recursive left call
        addNode(root.left, level+1);
    }
    if (root.right != null) {                     // recursive right call
        addNode(root.right, level+1);
    }

    return;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Node root = new Node();  // populate your tree here
addNode(root, 1);        // make initial call to recursive method here
```